# How to read file which contains 16-bit hex value?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a file like this:

```
\u9515\u7691\u853c\u788d\u7231
\u9515\u7691\u853c\u788d\u7231
\u9515\u7691\u853c\u788d\u7231
```

now I want to read this file to print string, I do this like this:

```
with open(fi, "rb") as fi:
    print(fi.readline().strip().decode("utf-8"))
```

but I find that it still print

```
\u9515\u7691\u853c\u788d\u7231
```

how can I get the real string:

```
锕皑蔼碍爱
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can decode your string using `unicode-escape`

```
line = "\\u9515\\u7691\\u853c\\u788d\\u7231"
print line.decode("unicode-escape")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your decode function treats your data as regular string. Try doing it like this:

```
with open(fi, "rb") as fi:
    data = fi.readline().strip()
    encode_data = data.encode("utf-8")
    print(encode_data.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: You sure u are using python3? 
@Ankush Rathi answer doesnt work on my python3 :D
Could u paste an error?

Comment: My pycharm is yelling: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"
Im using python36

Comment: I think you open file `with open(fi, "r") as fi`, change it to `with open(fi, "rb") as fi:`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, as this is a Python escaped string, you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
line = r"\u9515\u7691\u853c\u788d\u7231"
print(ast.literal_eval('u"' + line + '"')
```

gives as expected:

```
锕皑蔼碍爱
```

Comment: I got error like this: `AttributeError: module 'ast' has no attribute 'litteral_eval''`

Comment: @roger: My bad. It is `literal_eval` with one single `t`. Fixed.

Comment: I test it in python3, it works fine, but in python2, it doesn't

Comment: @roger: I forgot the `u` unicode indicator. It is a no-op in Python3 but generate a unicode string in Python2